# MySQL int definition explanation

Tags: mysql, definition, biginteger

For years I have been under the assumption when I create a new column of type bigint(12) for a MySQL table that the field is limited to integers with up to 12 digits. However, I recently noticed that values up to 16 digits are able to be written into and selected out of a bigint(12) defined column without any warnings or issues.

Can someone please help me understand why this is the case and what that column definition actually means? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bigint(12) is not truncated at all. The 12 is used for display purposes.

Have a look at [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

> **Numeric Type Attributes**
>
> MySQL supports an extension for
>   optionally specifying the display
>   width of integer data types in
>   parentheses following the base keyword
>   for the type. For example, INT(4)
>   specifies an INT with a display width
>   of four digits. This optional display
>   width may be used by applications to
>   display integer values having a width
>   less than the width specified for the
>   column by left-padding them with
>   spaces. (That is, this width is
>   present in the metadata returned with
>   result sets. Whether it is used or not
>   is up to the application.)
>
> *The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored
>   in the column. Nor does it prevent
>   values wider than the column display
>   width from being displayed correctly.*

Comment: so what you're telling me is that by specifying the 12, I'm not actually saving anything in terms of resources and that it's only an optional value that a display program can choose whether or not to ignore. Basically if I use bigint(X) that it can store the full range of values that a bigint can store and will allocate disk space appropriately for that?

Comment: I believe that is what the documentation says.

Comment: Mind blowing. I asked a few people who have spent over 10 years working in ops and they couldn't explain it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

read `Numeric Type Attributes` section from MySql documentation [INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)